# Make Datepicker look on Android 4.0 as 2.x

Tags: android, datepicker

Is there a way to make the datepicker in android 4.0 look like the easy one on 2.x devices? I don't really wanna to use a button with a dialog, but that is absolutely enormous, i don't want the "calendar" thing.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found this method in the picker (works with apk>=11):

```
picker.setCalendarViewShown(false);
```

It works for me.

Answer (score 2):

System components look depends on the platform. You may be able (or not) to influence things like colors, but not functionality (unless you implement your own logic or layout). So in general, answer to your question is "No".